# Apply CSS style only to specific li element

Tags: css

I have this menu :

```
<ul class="elementor-nav-menu">
    <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fuel</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Find Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to add `border-bottom` style only to **Locations, Fuel, contact** on hover.

**To do that I am using the following CSS:**

```
.elementor-nav-menu li:not(:nth-child(3n)):hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

But It seems like not working. The code adds the style on the last element as well as the last element of the dropdown menu too which I don't want.

Comment: can you not just a separate class to those three items?

Comment: @andymccullough you mean I should add a class on those 3 elements?

Comment: Yes, add a class to these elements and just target this class.

Comment: Is there any other way without adding class?

Comment: And _Find us_ with or without border ? For me it seems to work fine Except that it is applied to _sub-items3_ this way

Comment: Find Us without border.

Comment: I want to add border-bottom style only to Locations, Fuel, contact on hover.

Comment: Im not aware of a good practice-way to apply any css rules by the elements content. If i understand you right you want to Style the Element with Locations, Fuel, Contact no matter in which position they are. you can do that with JavaScript but not with pure CSS and HTML, not in any good way.

Comment: @andymccullough sometime a simple solution is work :) I am using a class for those 3 elements. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `.elementor-nav-menu > li:not(:nth-child(3)):not(:last-child):hover {  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;}` is also another way to write your selector ;)

Comment: using all the pseudo-selectors will work, until you add more nav items or whatever in the future, then you have to try and rework your css to match.  If you want those 3 specific links to be styled in a certain way, regardless of any other links, I would just target them directly with their own classes. In a nutshell, write your code to represent your logic of when you want to style the links in a certain way.  Is it those specific links v.s. is it always going to be all but 3rd and last immediate child items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer relies on the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) selector, which only is selecting direct children of an element.

```css
.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(1):hover,
.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(2):hover,
.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4):hover
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="elementor-nav-menu">
    <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fuel</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Find Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to add border-bottom style only to Locations, Fuel, contact on hover.

Comment: Sorry, should have read more carefully, I've updated the anwser.

Comment: What a simple solution! I should use my brain more :)

Comment: To stop the jumping you should make a default style for the li as `border-bottom: 3px solid transparent`. On hover this will be rendered into that what you wish and voila.

Comment: you can also mix selector to filter tags , here `.elementor-nav-menu > li:not(:nth-child(3)):not(:last-child):hover {  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;}` works too ;)

Comment: This would be more elegant @G-Cyrillus. Good point.